# Different result every time

Tags: python

So I've had a task where I was given a string that contains calls (call duration,call number) and the task was to count the total duration.
There were some extra checks:
if duration > 5 minutes than it counts only minutes (150 cents/minute)
for the phone number which has the biggest duration, calls are free so it's 0 cents.

I wrote the code and the correct answer has to be 900. But when I run the code the result is always different. Sometimes is 0, sometimes is 900. Whats the reason?

```
import re

string = '''
00:01:07,400-234-090\n
00:05:01,701-080-080\n
00:05:00,400-234-090\n
'''

pattern = r'(?P<duration>[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}),(?P<phone>[\d]{3}-[\d]{3}-[\d]{3})'

duration = {}


for s in string.split('\n'):
    match = re.fullmatch(pattern, s)
    if match:
        hour, minutes, sec = match.group('duration').split(':')
        sec = int(sec)
        minutes = int(minutes)
        hour = int(hour) * (minutes * sec)
        if minutes < 5:
            total = (hour + (minutes * 60) + sec) * 3
            print(s + ' - matched! Total seconds:' + str(total))
            if not match.group('phone') in duration:
                duration[match.group('phone')] = total
            else:
                duration[match.group('phone')] += total
        elif minutes >= 5 and sec == 0:
            total = (minutes * 150)
            print(s + ' - matched! Total seconds:' + str(total))
            if not match.group('phone') in duration:
                duration[match.group('phone')] = total
            else:
                duration[match.group('phone')] += total
        elif minutes >= 5 and sec >= 1:
            total = (minutes * 150) + 150
            print(s + ' - matched! Total seconds:' + str(total))
            if not match.group('phone') in duration:
                duration[match.group('phone')] = total
            else:
                duration[match.group('phone')] += total

for k, v in duration.items():
    if v == max(duration.values()):
        duration[k] = 0
print(sum(duration.values()))
```

Comment: I get the same result each time I run this, no matter where I run it. There are three "matched!" lines with 201, 900, 750 seconds, and the final output is 0.

Comment: @abarnert it has to be 900 because the total amount of 2 numbers is 900 and 950. 950 is a larger one so it equals 0. Why does it behave like that? It has to be 900

Comment: Ah, you're probably running on a version of Python where dictionaries (with string keys) have an explicitly random order, like 3.5, while I'm running on a version where dictionaries mainly insert order, 3.7. That's why you get different results each time, while I always get the same result. When you get 900, it's basically pure luck—the strings happen to be hash-randomized into an order that makes the `max(duration.values())` zero out exactly the right entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are finding the max of your dict values inside the for loop.

```
>>> duration
{'400-234-090': 951, '701-080-080': 900}
>>> 
>>> for k, v in duration.items():
...     if v == max(duration.values()):
...         duration[k] = 0
... 
>>> duration
{'400-234-090': 0, '701-080-080': 0}
>>>
>>> print(sum(duration.values()))
0
```

Just calculate it once, outside the loop to get the expected answer.

```
>>> duration 
{'400-234-090': 951, '701-080-080': 900}
>>>
>>> max_val = max(duration.values())
>>> for k, v in duration.items():
...     if v == max_val:
...         duration[k] = 0
... 
>>> print(sum(duration.values()))
900
```

Answer (score 1):

You get random results because you are recalculating the max inside the loop on the dictionary: the key order is not guaranteed to be consistent across different runs. Add `m = max(duration.values())` before the loop and change the if in the loop from `if v == max(duration.values())` to `if v == m`. It will work every time.